# How to apply 2 regex patterns simultaneously in grep

Tags: grep

I would like to check for 2 patterns across a piece of text (a total of 4 delimiters).
Either one of the two patterns matches is fine.  However when they qualify, I would like the results to be next to each other side by side.

This is the INPUT TEXT (it contains two separate long lines. Actual input text is much more. I have chosen relevent snippets as shown below):

```
Query Response #5: [2659] ID,(0010,0030) DA #8 [19801024] PatientÆs Birth Date,,,(0020,000D) UI #42 Station Title,,,>(0040,0002) DA #8 [20301212] Scheduled Procedure Step Start Date,,,>(0040,0003) TM #4Information

Query Response #6: ID, (0010,0030) DA #8 [19410203] PatientÆs Birth Date, Title,,,>(0040,0002) DA #8 [20210826] Scheduled Procedure Step Start Date, FIND]
```

This is the DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
19801024 20301212
19410203 20210826
```

There are 2 pairs of delimiters. The 1st set of delimiters is this:

```
(0010,0030) DA #8 [
] Patient
```

The 2nd set of delimiters is this:

```
(0040,0002) DA #8 [
] Scheduled Procedure Step Start Date
```

I am able to apply each pair of delimiter by itself.  Specifically, when I do this:

```
grep -o -P "(?<=0010,0030\) DA #8 \[).*(?=\] Patient)"
```

I get this output:

```
19801024
19410203
```

When I apply this 2nd pair of delimiter like this below:

```
grep -o -P "(?<=0040,0002\) DA #8 \[).*(?=\] Scheduled Procedure Step Start Date)"
```

I get this output:

```
20301212
20210826
```

How do I issue a correct combined grep command such that the output result is as shown below? :

```
19801024 20301212
19410203 20210826
```

I tried this following approach without success:

```
grep -e "(?<=0040,0002\) DA #8 \[).*(?=\] Scheduled Procedure Step Start Date)" -e "(?<=0010,0030\) DA #8 \[).*(?=\] Patient)"
```

The error message I get is follows:

```
grep: Unmatched ) or \)
```

Thanks in advance. I hope my question is clear.  (Please note I'm using grep under Windows10. The outer quatations marks have to be double quotation marks)

Answer (score 2):

This is actually job for `sed` more than `grep`:

```sh
sed -E 's/.*\(0010,0030\) DA #8 \[([^]]+)\] Patient.*\(0040,0002\) DA #8 \[([^]]+)\] Scheduled Procedure Step Start Date.*/\1 \2/' file

19801024 20301212
19410203 20210826
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples only, please try following `awk` program. Written and tested in GNU `awk` should work in any `awk`. Simple explanation would be, making  `PatientÆs Birth Date` as field separator for all lines then in main program checking 1st field if its equal to regex `^Query Response.*DA #8 \[[0-9]+\]$` then getting value between `[` and `]`(excluding `[` and `]`) and saving it into `val` variable. Then checking condition if 2nd field matches to `^,.*DA #8[[:space:]]+` then  again getting values between `[` and `]` and printing val variable and current $2's value, which is required output.

```
awk -F' PatientÆs Birth Date' '
$1~/^Query Response.*DA #8 \[[0-9]+\]$/{
  val=""
  gsub(/.*\[|\]$/,"",$1)
  val=$1
}
$2~/^,.*DA #8[[:space:]]+/{
  gsub(/.*\[|\].*/,"",$2)
  print val,$2
}
'  Input_file
```